# sphinx: received zero sized searchd response

Tags: search, sphinx

I'm running sphinx on mac os x lion. In the config file I've set workers = thread. When I try to query a search with these settings I get an error saying received zero sized searchd response. However when I start searchd with --nodetach option it works fine. Also changing workers = fork solves the problem but I need to use rt indexing and so I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is no mistype? Right variant is:

```
workers = threads
```

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-workers.html